# mysql query - syntax error - cannot find out why

Tags: mysql, syntax

im tearing my hair out over this one. A query is throwing an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM, SUBJECT, DATE, READ, MAIL ) VALUES ( 'EJackson', 'dfdf', '1270974101', 'fa' at line 1

I printed out the query to see what could be the problem:

```
INSERT INTO db.tablename ( FROM, SUBJECT, DATE, READ, MAIL ) VALUES ( 'EJackson', 'dfdf', '1270974299', 'false', 'dfdsfdsfd' )
```

and finaly the structure consists of:

```
CREATE TABLE db.tablename (
  `ID` int(12) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `FROM` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `SUBJECT` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `DATE` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `READ` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `MAIL` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I can't find anything wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the insert statement, "FROM" is a keyword in SQL so you need to enclose it in backquotes like you have in your create table statement.

So it'll be like:

```
INSERT INTO db.tablename (`FROM`, `SUBJECT`, `DATE`, `READ`, `MAIL` ) VALUES ( 'EJackson', 'dfdf', '1270974299', 'false', 'dfdsfdsfd' )
```

Comment: thank you! How come you have to enclose all in backquotes tho?

Comment: Since FROM is a reserved keyword, if you use it as a column name the backquotes around it tell the parser not to recognize it as a keyword. Anything which is not a keyword doesn't need backquotes but it can just be safer to use them all the time.

Comment: It's just how you should generally write your queries. Best practice.

Comment: Thank you, never wrote queries with backquotes around the column name but will do from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't FROM a reserved word in MySQL?

Comment: When I wrote my answer, there was no other...